# Get type of an uninitialized slice

Tags: go, reflection, slice

I want to return a type of an `interface{}`, while the input value might be `var m []*MyModel`

I've managed to get to the type `*MyModel`, while `MyModel` not as a pointer seems to be unreachable to me.

```
func getType( m interface{} ) reflect.Type {

    t := reflect.TypeOf( m );   
    v := reflect.ValueOf( m );

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {    

        if v.IsValid() && !v.IsNil() {          
            return getType( v.Elem().Interface() );         
        }

        panic( "We have a problem" );   

    }

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Slice {

        if v.Len() == 0 {           

            s := reflect.MakeSlice( t , 1 , 1 );            
            return getType( s.Interface() );    

        }

        return getType( v.Index( 0 ).Interface() );

    }

    return t;

}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment? That's a nice feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Type.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) to get the type's element type, which works for `Array`, `Chan`, `Map`, `Ptr` and `Slice`.

You may run a loop and "navigate" to the type's element type until the type is not a pointer nor a slice (nor array, chan, map if you need so).

So the simple solution is this:

```
func getElemType(a interface{}) reflect.Type {
    for t := reflect.TypeOf(a); ; {
        switch t.Kind() {
        case reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
            t = t.Elem()
        default:
            return t
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
type MyModel struct{}

fmt.Println(getElemType(MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType(&MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType([]MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType([]*MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType(&[]*MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType(&[]****MyModel{}))
fmt.Println(getElemType(&[][]**[]*[]***MyModel{}))
var p *[][]**[]*[]***MyModel
fmt.Println(p) // It's nil!
fmt.Println(getElemType(p))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qBW3EIN2Jl)):

```
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
main.MyModel
<nil>
main.MyModel
```

As you can see, no matter how "deep" we go with slices and pointers (`&[][]**[]*[]***MyModel{}`), `getElemType()` is able to extract `main.MyModel`.

One thing to note is that in my solution I used [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) and not [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). Go is a statically typed language, so the type information is there even if pointers and slice elements are not "populated", even if we pass a "typed" `nil` such as `p`, we're still able to navigate through the "type chain".

**Note:** The above `getElemType()` panics if called with an untyped `nil` value, e.g. `getElemType(nil)`, because in this case there is no type information available. To defend this, you may add a simple check:

```
if a == nil {
    return nil
}
```

**Note #2:** Since the implementation contains a loop without limiting iteration count, values of recursive types will drive it into an endless loop, such as:

```
type RecType []RecType
getElemType(RecType{}) // Endless loop!
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. I do not really understand, why you need the `for` loop, but it works, rather than just `t := reflect.TypeOf(a)`. Could you point at an explanation maybe?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov If you start with the type `[]**MyModel`, `Elem()` will return you a type describing `**MyModel`. Calling `Elem()` again will return you `*MyModel`, and calling `Elem()` again you get `MyModel`. A call to `Elem()` strips one "type-layer" . You need a loop to remove all "layers" until what you have left is the "bare" type.

Comment: As simple as that... Thank you very much!